# get default value if don't find elements with iterfind

Tags: python, xml

I have these code to extract of xml file some elements:

```
for general in tree.iter('FOLDER'):

    nameFolder = general.attrib.get('FOLDER_NAME')          
    for job_nodeOS in tablaGeneral.iterfind(".//JOB[@APPL_TYPE='OS']"):
                       
            listaOS.clear()
            
            
            listaOS.append(job_name)
            listaOS.append(nameFolder)
            listaOS.append(daily)
            
            for job_nodeOS3 in job_nodeOS.iterfind("ON"):
                            listaOS.append(job_nodeOS3.get('STMT',"NO APLICA")) 
                            listaOS.append(job_nodeOS3.get('CODE',"NO APLICA")) 
                            for job_nodeOS4 in job_nodeOS3.iterfind("DOMAIL"):             
                                listaOS.append(job_nodeOS5.get('SUBJECT',"NO APLICA")) 
                                listaOS.append(job_nodeOS5.get('MESSAGE',"NO APLICA")) 

            for variable_name in variablesOS:
                
                variable_node = job_nodeOS.find(f"./VARIABLE[@NAME='{variable_name}']")
                variable_value = variable_node.get("VALUE", default_value) if variable_node is not None else default_value
                #print(job_name, variable_name.lstrip("%"), "=", variable_value)
                listaOS.append(variable_value)
```

My problem is that if the clause for don't find any occurrences, I need listaOS add default values ('NO APLICA').

A piece of code xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Exported at 11-06-2022 17:14:50-->
<DEFTABLE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Folder.xsd">
    <FOLDER SERVER="PROD" VERSION="800" PLATFORM="UNIX" FOLDER_NAME="PALNF" >
        <JOB ID="256" APPLICATION="HOUSE" SUBAPP="SERVER" JOBNAME="JOBA" APPL_TYPE="OS">
            <SHOUT WHEN="LATESUB" TIME="0825" URGENCY="R" DEST="DESTINATION" MESSAGE="HI" DAYSOFFSET="0" />
            <ON STMT="*" CODE="*NETWORK*">
                <DOACTION ACTION="NOTOK" />
                <DOMAIL URGENCY="U" DEST="EXMAPLE@EXMAPLE.COM" SUBJECT="SUBJECT" MESSAGE="HI" />
            </ON>
        </JOB>
        <JOB ID="1" APPLICATION="OFFICE" SUBAPP="Google" JOBNAME="Google_Update_Task_Machine_UA" APPL_TYPE="OS">
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PARM1" VALUE="GoogleUpdate.exe" />
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%PARM2" VALUE="/ua /installsource scheduler" />
        </JOB>
    </FOLDER>
    <FOLDER SERVER="PROD" VERSION="800" PLATFORM="UNIX" FOLDER_NAME="PALNF_CALENDARIO">
        <JOB ID="2" APPLICATION="APP" SUBAPP="SUB" JOBNAME="NOSCHEDULER" APPL_TYPE="OS" />
        <JOB ID="3" APPLICATION="APP" SUBAPP="SUB" JOBNAME="NOSCHEDULER_CONMONHDAYS" APPL_TYPE="OS" />
    </FOLDER>
</DEFTABLE>
```

Do you know how could I get that?

Thanks and sorry for my English!

Comment: Please add an example of input and output for your code as it's not clear what the xml is like.

Comment: Hi! I've edited the code. Problem is that I need filed ('NO APPLY')  if the for don't find what I try to get

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That includes code that runs and well-formed XML.

Comment: @mzjn I've update the main post with code